# How do I find the other threads that send back the signal when one thread calls WaitOne?

Tags: c#, multithreading

One of the things I'm having a hard time to understand in multi-threaded programming is that fact that when one thread reaches a line that calls `WaitOne()`, how do I know which other threads are involved? Where or how can I find (or understand) how the `WaitHandle` receives the signal? For example, I'm looking at this code right now:

```
private void RunSync(object state, ElapsedEventArgs elapsedEventArgs)
    {
        _mutex.WaitOne();
        using (var sync = GWSSync.BuildSynchronizer(_log))
        {
            try
            {
                sync.Syncronize();
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                _log.Write(string.Format("Error during synchronization : {0}", ex));
            }
        }
        _mutex.ReleaseMutex();
        _syncTimer.Interval = TimeBeforeNextSync().TotalMilliseconds;
        _syncTimer.Start();
    }
```

There are a few methods like this in the file (i.e RunThis(), RunThat()). These methods run inside a Windows service and are called when a Timer elapses. Each of these methods are called using different Timers and set up like this:

```
        //Synchro
        var timeBeforeFirstSync = TimeBeforeNextSync();
        _syncTimer = new System.Timers.Timer(timeBeforeFirstSync.TotalMilliseconds);
        _syncTimer.AutoReset = false;
        _syncTimer.Elapsed += RunSync;
        _syncTimer.Start();
```

I understand that when the Timer elapses, the `RunSync` method will run. But when it hits the `WaitOne()` line, the thread is blocked. But who is it waiting for? Which "other" thread will send the signal?

Comment: I would run "Find Usages" on the mutex variable.

Comment: @usr That wouldn't necessary find all usages if the mutex is named - but yeah, it's a start. But with just what we have to go on, it's entirely possible it's a (poor) attempt to prevent two simultaneous executions of the timer callback. Being a mutex, though, it's far more likely it's synchronizing with another process on the machine - unless the original author didn't know the difference between a monitor and a mutex.

Comment: After reading @usr comments I realized there are other timers starting other methods similar to the one above. I reworded my question to explain it better.

Comment: If you want to find that with a debugger attached you might find [this thinktecture blog](http://weblogs.thinktecture.com/ingo/2006/08/who-is-blocking-that-mutex---fun-with-windbg-cdb-and-kd.html)  useful.

Comment: How does your `_mutex` variable be declared?

Comment: @VMAtm, _mutex is declared in the class where these methods exist and declared as a private readonly variable. A Mutex is sent to this class via one of the constructor parameters and it is assigned to this local variable. This windows service is called by TopShelf which starts the Windows service. The class also has a parameterless constructor.

Answer (score 1):

`WaitHandle` is an abstraction, as stated in the documentation:

> Encapsulates operating system–specific objects that wait for exclusive access to shared resources.

You don't know which other **threads** are involved, but you **do** know which other **code** is involved by checking the usage of the handle (`_mutex` in your case). Every `WaitHandle` derived class inherits `WaitOne`, but what happens after successful wait and how it's get signalled is specific. For instance, in your example `_mutex` most probably is a `Mutex` class, so `WaitOne` acts like "wait until it's free and take ownership" while the `ReleaseMutex` acts like "release ownership and signal". With that in mind, it should be obvious what all these methods do - ensuring that while `RunThis` you cannot `RunThat` and vise versa.